# Spring Boot with Angular and Thymeleaf frontend technologies

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I want to mix different frontend technology in my Spring Boot application. For example if someone go to 'localhost:8080/main' I want to serve main apliaction written in Thymeleaf template. If some go to 'localhost:8080/user' I would like to serve apllicaction written in Angular framework. Any request which match '/user/**' pattern should return angular main index.html. Any one know how to mix technology? Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Interesting question, i never tried this before, but i am definitely gonna do some poc on this and I'll come back to you